# Create custom type for an array

Tags: typescript

I am using Typescript with Redux and want to put a type for initial state.

Examples I have seen assume initial state is key value pairs like:

```
const INITIAL_STATE: State = {
    id: '1',
    firstName: 'Michael',
    lastName: 'Black',
  }
```

where the type is defined as

```
export interface State {
  id: string
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}
```

How about if the type is defined as

```
const INITIAL_STATE: State = [
  {
    id: '1',
    firstName: 'Michael',
    lastName: 'Black',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    firstName: 'Tony',
    lastName: 'Montana',
  }
]
```

How would the type definition look? I did try look for answer as it looks like it should be simple to do but couldn't find anything...

Edit:

I guess I could do

```
const INITIAL_STATE: Array<State> = [
  {
    id: '1',
    firstName: 'Michael',
    lastName: 'Black',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    firstName: 'Tony',
    lastName: 'Montana',
  }
]
```

But how about if I wanted a new definition, CustomerState?

Something like

```
export interface CustomerState Array<State>
```

which is a syntax error of course.

Comment: Um `Array<State>` or `State []` ?

Comment: Tried..'export interface CustomerState Array<State>'

Comment: i think i know the problem. see update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> export interface CustomerState Array

I would

```
export interface Person {
  id: string
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}
export type State = Person[];
const INITIAL_STATE: State = [
  {
    id: '1',
    firstName: 'Michael',
    lastName: 'Black',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    firstName: 'Tony',
    lastName: 'Montana',
  }
]
```